# Xamarin JAR Binding Library

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, wechat, xamarin-binding

I'm trying to binding WeChat SDK into Xamarin using .jar file from [WeChat SDK Downloads](http://open.wechat.com/cgi-bin/newreadtemplate?t=overseas_open/docs/mobile/downloads).

I had follow the tutorials from [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/). Unfortunately, I'm having these 2 issues when trying to rebuild the solutions:

> - Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>     Error   CS0102  The type 'BaseResp' already contains a definition for 'ErrCode'
> - Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>     Error   CS0102  The type 'WXMediaMessage' already contains a definition for 'MediaObject'

Can you guys give me some guidance please. Thanks in advance for help. :)

Comment: can you check BaseResp contains 2 property as ErrCode and also WXMediaMessage contains 2 property as MediaObject? if so please remove a entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by editing code of ***Metadata.xml*** inside folder ***Transforms***.

Just add 2 lines of code. After this, clean and build your solutions:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.tencent.mm.sdk.modelbase']/class[@name='BaseResp']/field[@name='errCode']" name="managedName">errCode</attr>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.tencent.mm.sdk.modelmsg']/class[@name='WXMediaMessage']/field[@name='mediaObject']" name="managedName">mediaObject</attr>
```

**Note**: You can double-clicked on the errors to navigate you to the corresponding XPath field reference.

[image]

For **more information**, read [Java Bindings Metadata](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata/).